# Android Studio App Inspection does not show database at times

Tags: android, android-studio, database-inspector

I am using Arctic Fox 2020.3.1. I am not able to find a pattern that will make App Inspection work reliably - that is want to be able to inspect whenever I want. After dis/reconnecting, invalidating cache restart, app restart, app clear data and restart, app reinstall, etc. sometimes makes it possible to view the database other times I just this staying forever:

[image]

I can do the steps above to get it working but then I lose the moment where I need to inspect the data.

I tried killing adb process and reconnect, no use. Stop/start inspector from AS doesn't help. What is the sure shot way of getting App Inspection work?

Comment: For me, in 2021.3.1 Patch 1 (and before), it does not show at all (even though tools like adb, file explorer and layout inspector work).